# Working out Stokes' law

Tags: vector-analysis

A couple of weeks ago my professor gave me a paper on Stokes' law and how to derive it from the equations of motion and continuity. (http://www.ux.uis.no/~finjord/pdf/flu/stokes.pdf)

In one of the parts (the one to derive eq 4.18) I found the following step, where $u_0$ is a constant vector and $f$ only depends on $r$:
$\nabla^2($grad div $ - \nabla^2)(\nabla f \times u_0) = - (\nabla^2)^2(\nabla f \times u_0)$

However I don't see why the first term in the LHS disappears. I did check it on WolframAlpha, but this only tells me it's zero and not why.

Can anybody explain why it is zero?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really just straightforward calculation, assuming that $f$ has at least continuous second partial derivatives (Schwarz theorem):
$$\nabla \times u_0 = \partial_i f \phantom{0} u_{0j}\phantom{0} \varepsilon_{ijk} \vec{e}_k$$
therefore
$$div (\nabla \times u_0) = \partial_{ik} f \phantom{0} u_{0j}\phantom{0} \varepsilon_{ijk} = 0$$
If it is not clear why this term is zero, I suggest to think about symmetry properties.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. I must have made a mistake somewhere with the indices in my calculation as I couldn't apply the symmetry properties.